# Android change ProgressBar thickness

Tags: android, android-styles, android-progressbar

I am using a circular ProgressBar in my app, but it looks very thick. It does not look how it should on Android > 4.

When I create a new project and use the ProgressBar I get the correct thickness. Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Did you try without the `style`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The progress bar looks the "modern" way when the application's theme is `Theme.Holo` (or one that is derived from it, such as `Theme.Holo.Light`, &c).

If your application is for **API 11+**, then just use Holo. To do this, you just need to change the `android:theme` attribute in the `<application>` element in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Otherwise, you'll need to implement a theme selector, as described in the Android Developer Guides: [Select a theme based on platform version](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme)

Comment: @matiash- i currently use  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" because i need full screen.

Comment: How do i make the app full screen